# How to store a numeric value which can have other statuses in a database?

Tags: database

I need to store a set of numbers in a database which are imported from a spreadsheet.

Sometimes a number is just a number.  But in other times, a value can be "missing", "N/A", or blank and these all represent different things.

What would be a good approach to store these numbers in the database?  Originally I only had to account for N/A.  So I made it -1 as I imported them (this only works if the number can never be negative obviously).  I could use other negative numbers for other statuses.  However, that seems clunky to me.

Should I store the numbers as string then apply conversion at use time?
Should I create a matching table that stores different statuses of each value?

Answer (score 4):

You need two fields - status and number

Comment: Looks like the consensus is that I need two columns.  So this Q isn't specific to Scott but for all:  If I have 20 columns then do I need 20 extra status columns, totaling 40?  That seems too much.  That's why I originally thought that having a separate table to store the statuses would be cleaner.  Any thoughts?

Comment: The numbers should be in a separate table as if the status is not numeric there is nothing to put in the number field

Answer (score 2):

Using `-1` was a bad design from the start: you should have been using `NULL`, and at this point you could add a secondary column to store a status code for why a `NULL` value is there.

Answer (score 1):

I agree on needing two fields status and number (so I agree with KM and Scott )

The reasons included that if you have anything but numbers from the spreadsheet (this includes your -1 and also NULLs) then aggregate functions like SUM and average will not give correct answers.

Having an extra field to give the status whose values include missing, N/A and numeric for when you have a number allows you to be able to query for these statuses.

Using NULL is not myuch use here as it would not differentiate between the missing and N/A values

Answer (score 0):

do not store as a string and convert on use, that is the worst, because you will have to expend resources to convert every time (forever) you use the data.

Store two fields:

```
NumberValue   number
NumberStatus  char(1)  -"M"=missing, "N"=n/a, "B"=blank, "V"=have a numeric value
```